# Vim - surround.vim - s key not working

Tags: vim, surround

When I select some code by v key and press s to surround and closed in brackets i receive this error:

```
 surround.vim Visual mode s has been remove in favor of S
```

How to revert this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just map it back to <kbd>S</kbd>?

```
vmap s S
```

Comment: Or `xmap`, if you care about select mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to use <kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as suggested. See [this](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/commit/f6c9d3beb2d11959d22b2555636aeb0c37e66aa1) for further details.

Comment: You have linked back to this question